# HashMap Overwriting

Tags: hashmap

I have written the following :

```
HashMap<String, String> formMappingData= new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> formData= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

When I am iterating the `formMappingData` I get to see only the values of the latest iteration and the previous iteration values are updated with the latest.

The code as below

```
         for(Object formPts : data) {

             if( formPts instanceof Form) {
             System.out.println(" Form is found");
             Form frm = (Form) formPts;
            // String accessFrmRefs = frm.getAccessRefs();
             fID = "#"+frm.getId();

             System.out.println("The form id is "+ " "+ fID);
             List<com.integra.PLMXML.Form.UserData.UserValue> frmuserVal = frm.getUserData().getUserValue();

             for(com.integra.PLMXML.Form.UserData.UserValue uslVal : frmuserVal) 
             {              
                 if("dp_COMPONENT_NUMBER".equalsIgnoreCase(uslVal.getTitle())) {
                     //String parse_dp_comp = null;                      
                     String parse_dp_comp=uslVal.getValue();    
                     System.out.println("dp_component_number" +" "+ parse_dp_comp);
                     formMappingData.put("dp_COMPONENT_NUMBER", parse_dp_comp);

                 }

                 if("dp_SCALE".equalsIgnoreCase(uslVal.getTitle())) {


                    String  parse_dp_scale=uslVal.getValue();
                     System.out.println("dp_SCALE" +" "+ parse_dp_scale);
                     formMappingData.put("dp_SCALE", parse_dp_scale);
                 }

                 if("dp_MATERIAL".equalsIgnoreCase(uslVal.getTitle())) {

                     if(!uslVal.getValue().isEmpty() )
                     {
                        String parse_dp_material = uslVal.getValue();
                        System.out.println("parse_dp_material" + parse_dp_material);
                         formMappingData.put("dp_MATERIAL", parse_dp_material);
                     }else {
                         String parse_dp_material="Migrated Data";
                         System.out.println("parse_dp_material" + parse_dp_material);
                         formMappingData.put("dp_MATERIAL", parse_dp_material);

                     }
                 }

                 if("last_mod_date".equalsIgnoreCase(uslVal.getTitle())) {



                     if(!uslVal.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                         String parse_dp_last_mod_date=uslVal.getValue().toString();
                         System.out.println("parse_dp_last_mod_date" + parse_dp_last_mod_date);
                         formMappingData.put("parse_dp_last_mod_date", parse_dp_last_mod_date);

                     }else
                     {
                         String parse_dp_last_mod_date = new Date().toString();
                         System.out.println("parse_dp_last_mod_date" + parse_dp_last_mod_date);
                         formMappingData.put("parse_dp_last_mod_date", parse_dp_last_mod_date);
                     }

                 }



             if("owning_user".equalsIgnoreCase(uslVal.getTitle())) {

                 if(!uslVal.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                    String parse_dp_drawn=uslVal.getValue().toString();
                     System.out.println("parse_dp_drawn" + parse_dp_drawn);
                     formMappingData.put("parse_dp_drawn", parse_dp_drawn);

                 }else
                 {
                     String parse_dp_drawn = "Migrated Data";
                     System.out.println("parse_dp_drawn" + parse_dp_drawn);
                     formMappingData.put("parse_dp_drawn", parse_dp_drawn);
                 }
             }



             if("last_mod_date".equalsIgnoreCase(uslVal.getTitle())) {

                 if(!uslVal.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                    String parse_dp_usedon=uslVal.getValue().toString();
                     System.out.println("parse_dp_usedon" + parse_dp_usedon);
                     formMappingData.put("parse_dp_usedon", parse_dp_usedon);

                 }else
                 {
                     String parse_dp_usedon  = new Date().toString();
                     formMappingData.put("parse_dp_usedon", parse_dp_usedon);
                 }
             }
             //formData.put(fID, formMappingData);
         }

             //Add the hashmap details here
            formData.put(fID, formMappingData);

         }
     }`
```

Any Suggestions How do I solve this.

Comment: Could you clarify what your problem is? Currently it's a very short explanation that's comparably unclear and a huge chunk of code. Hard to understand your problem. Read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some good advice how to improve.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `formData.put(fID, formMappingData);` you are using the same reference each time. I.e. you have just one `formMappingData` map for all keys. `formMappingData.put` replaces the values in this single map.

You probably want to do `HashMap<String, String> formMappingData = new HashMap<String, String>();` for every `uslVal`.

Comment: HI Alexey, That is correct I am using the same reference each time and that is causing the data that is already there to be replaced.  I have found a way to handle this by appending the form id that I get to the key in the hash map of formData and when I am comparing the values later I using the form ID tag and extracting the values and printing them into an XML. Is there an better way to handle this.....Vilas

Comment: "Is there an better way to handle this" I already gave one in the second paragraph. Though I'd really use a class instead of a `Map` for `formMappingData` (given just the code you show).